# How to switch from SHA to SHA-1 in openssl

Tags: c++, openssl

In my application, before developers have used openssl version 1.0.1e [#include openssl/sha.h] and have used the function

```
unsigned char *SHA(const unsigned char *d, size_t n, unsigned char *md);
```

Now I need to upgrade the openssl version to 1.1.1 but when compiling with new version it is showing error at SHA function call.

Then, I tried replacing SHA() with SHA1() it got compiled but the output of SHA() and SHA1() are different, how can i achieve the same cryptographic hash function output as SHA() in the new version.

Comment: what is the error? Show your code, we need a [mcve]

Comment: I think [(looking at the header file)](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/deps/openssl/+/9cf78c7e3f296eaacbac515ec6a684ee8fcc48dd/openssl/crypto/sha/sha.h) `SHA(...)` may be an implementation of `SHA0` which is a slightly different hash to `SHA1` so (if I am right) I would expect them to produce different output.

Comment: Since SHA and SHA1 are different algorithms, you can not achieve the same output as SHA1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSL removed support for SHA-0 in 1.1.0 see https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2015/07/28/code-cleanup/.

You shouldn't be using SHA-0 for anything as it is completely broken: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHA-0